# ComoSerealizar json con id dinamico

Tags: c#

Tengo el siguiente JSON:

```js
{
  "-LY2_Np3-jTOC9T0-Xzb": {
      "Descripcion": "Se realizo una factura(p) en tienda: 3 por el usuario: ARMANDO",
      "Fecha": "2019-02-06",
      "Hora": "10:13:01 AM",
      "Monto": "10763.5",
      "Tipo": "Transaccion"
  },
  "-LY2j1Fbl195pooEich8": {
      "Descripcion": "Se realizo una factura(f) en tienda: 3 por el usuario: ARMANDO",
      "Fecha": "2019-02-06",
      "Hora": "10:55:10 AM",
      "Monto": "26900",
      "Tipo": "Transaccion"
  },
  "-LY2jyHCM1DtZAxdxt7W": {
      "Descripcion": "Se realizo una factura(p) en tienda: 3 por el usuario: ARMANDO",
      "Fecha": "2019-02-06",
      "Hora": "10:59:16 AM",
      "Monto": "29830",
      "Tipo": "Transaccion"
  },
  "-LY2nQxcbMGO0oP5vmOM": {
      "Descripcion": "Se realizo una factura(p) en tienda: 3 por el usuario: ARMANDO",
      "Fecha": "2019-02-06",
      "Hora": "11:14:24 AM",
      "Monto": "9830",
      "Tipo": "Transaccion"
  }
}
```

Como se puede observar el id es dinámico. ¿Cómo puedo SEREALIZAR este archivo en C#?

Comment: tienes que definir una clase con propiedades dinamica, en resumen no se puede, porque es una pesima estructura para un json, tiene sque usar array o list

Comment: Entiendo leandro. Lo que pasa es que firebase me pide el json de esa forma y firebase crea los json con el id dinamico, pero bueno intentare alguna otra forma de hacero. Gracias.

Comment: mm firebase crea json de esa forma, me suena extraño, es horrible esa estructura de json, cuando se puede usar array

Comment: Si de hecho esos id no los genero yo, los genera firebase comopor ejemplo este: -LY2j1Fbl195pooEich8.

Comment: Cuando uno hace un post le genera esos ids automaticamente

Comment: la verdad es que no conozco firebase como para decir porque lo realiza de esa forma, pero si es algo automatico entiendo que deberias poder pasarle una lista simple y que genere esas propiedades, serializando desde c# una clase no se puede. Solo podras hacerlo si armas en json como string o quizas si alguna libreria como json.net te permite definir properties dinamicamente

Answer (score 1):

Checa esta respuesta

```
var firebaseLookup = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string,Appeal>>(json);
var data = firebaseLookup.Values.ToList(); // or FirstOrDefault();
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34335114/derserialize-json-object-from-firebase-in-c-sharp